# Core data with to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, core-data

Hello I am saving number of lyrics paragraph for song Entity. now I want to update that lyrics

I used below code to update value. but it is creating new record.. and also tell to delete

```
- (void)editLyrics {

     [editBarbutton setTitle:@"Save"];



    lyrics  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Lyrics" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    lyrics.songLyrics = lyricsTextview.text;





    lyrics.startTime = startTimeText.text;






    lyrics.endTime = endTimeText.text;

     lyrics.lyricsSong = song;    
    NSError *error;
    // here's where the actual save happens, and if it doesn't we print something out to the onsole
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get present object before:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Lyrics"
                               inManagedObjectContext:self.moc]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"something what u like to filter"]];
NSArray *lyrics = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"Failed to executeFetchRequest to data store: %@ in function:%@", [error localizedDescription],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
lyrics = [lyrics lastObject]
```

Comment: I m getting lyrics objects and managedobjectcontext from previous view.. your code is not still creating new records